# Can benign software modify Widnows DLL files?

Tags: windows, operating-systems, file-access

On Windows (XP, 7, 8, NT ...): can *.dll* files be modified (in any manner) by benign programs/software already installed/running on the computer ?

Answer (score 1):

If the owner (user) of the process of the software has the ability to do so, then the software also can delete/replace/modify DLLs.